Docker Compose suddenly having trouble with Prisma and Jose
I have a dockerized Next.js project using Prisma. I was working on it as usual, didn't change anything about the Docker setup, the file locations or packages, I just wanted to rebuild the container to pull new environment variables.
Then I receive this error:
90.79 > hey-shop@0.1.0 postinstall
90.79 > prisma generate
90.79 
91.03 Error: Could not find Prisma Schema that is required for this command.
91.03 You can either provide it with `--schema` argument, set it as `prisma.schema` in your package.json or put it into the default location.
91.03 Checked following paths:
91.03 
91.03 schema.prisma: file not found
91.03 prisma/schema.prisma: file not found
91.03 prisma/schema: directory not found
91.03 
91.03 See also https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema-location
91.03 npm notice
91.03 npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.7.0 -> 10.8.1
91.03 npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.8.1
91.03 npm notice To update run: npm install -g npm@10.8.1
91.03 npm notice
91.03 npm error code 1
91.03 npm error path /app
91.03 npm error command failed
91.03 npm error command sh -c prisma generate
91.04 
91.04 npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2024-06-28T08_02_21_293Z-debug-0.log
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

This is my package.json scripts section:
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next-swagger-doc-cli next-swagger-doc.json && next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "resetdb": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test npx prisma db push --force-reset && npx prisma db seed",
    "postinstall": "prisma generate",
    "generate-docs": "next-swagger-doc-cli next-swagger-doc.json",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest",
    "test:watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --watch"
  },
  "prisma": {
    "seed": "tsx prisma/seed.ts"
  },

Until then I had no issues running these scripts. It also makes no difference to the error when I specify --schema='/prisma/schema.prisma'. My file structure is the following:

/root

package.json

/prisma

schema.prisma





When I remove the postinstall script, this part seems to work. I don't need the postinstall anymore anyways - it was for generating an erd, but the corresponding package has vulnerabilities.
However, now my auth middleware creates trouble, especially Jose, which I use for JWTs.
web-1       |  ○ Compiling / ...
web-1       |  ⨯ ./node_modules/jose/dist/node/esm/lib/decrypt_key_management.js
web-1       | Attempted import error: 'normalizePrivateKey' is not exported from '../runtime/normalize_key.js' (imported as 'normalize').
web-1       | 
web-1       | Import trace for requested module:
web-1       | ./node_modules/jose/dist/node/esm/lib/decrypt_key_management.js
web-1       | ./node_modules/jose/dist/node/esm/jwe/flattened/decrypt.js
web-1       | ./node_modules/jose/dist/node/esm/index.js
web-1       | ./app/lib/auth.ts
web-1       | ./app/lib/utils/api-authorization.ts
web-1       | ./app/(general)/layout.tsx
web-1       |  ⨯ ./node_modules/jose/dist/node/esm/lib/decrypt_key_management.js
web-1       | Attempted import error: 'normalizePrivateKey' is not exported from '../runtime/normalize_key.js' (imported as 'normalize').
web-1       | 
web-1       | Import trace for requested module:
web-1       | ./node_modules/jose/dist/node/esm/lib/decrypt_key_management.js
web-1       | ./node_modules/jose/dist/node/esm/jwe/flattened/decrypt.js
web-1       | ./node_modules/jose/dist/node/esm/index.js
web-1       | ./app/lib/auth.ts
web-1       | ./app/ui/search/pagination.tsx
web-1       | ./app/(general)/page.tsx
web-1       |  ⨯ ./node_modules/jose/dist/node/esm/lib/decrypt_key_management.js
web-1       | Attempted import error: 'normalizePrivateKey' is not exported from '../runtime/normalize_key.js' (imported as 'normalize').
web-1       | 
web-1       | Import trace for requested module:
web-1       | ./node_modules/jose/dist/node/esm/lib/decrypt_key_management.js
web-1       | ./node_modules/jose/dist/node/esm/jwe/flattened/decrypt.js
web-1       | ./node_modules/jose/dist/node/esm/index.js
web-1       | ./app/lib/auth.ts
web-1       | ./app/ui/search/pagination.tsx
web-1       | ./app/(general)/page.tsx
web-1       |  ⨯ ./node_modules/jose/dist/node/esm/lib/decrypt_key_management.js
web-1       | Attempted import error: 'normalizePrivateKey' is not exported from '../runtime/normalize_key.js' (imported as 'normalize').
web-1       | 
web-1       | Import trace for requested module:
web-1       | ./node_modules/jose/dist/node/esm/lib/decrypt_key_management.js
web-1       | ./node_modules/jose/dist/node/esm/jwe/flattened/decrypt.js
web-1       | ./node_modules/jose/dist/node/esm/index.js
web-1       | ./app/lib/auth.ts
web-1       | ./app/ui/search/pagination.tsx
web-1       | ./app/(general)/page.tsx

And this is the part where I get stuck. I don't understand why suddenly this error appears. I am on a recent version of jose, have checked their forums and find nothing.
Here is my docker-compose:
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "sh -c 'pg_isready -U postgres -d postgres'"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - VERCEL_TOKEN=${VERCEL_TOKEN}
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app/app
      - ./prisma:/app/prisma
      - ./public:/app/public
      - ./swagger:/app/swagger
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 5555:5555
    depends_on:
      - postgres

volumes:
  postgres-data:

Here is my Dockerfile:
FROM node:20

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

RUN npm install --global vercel@latest

COPY . .

ARG VERCEL_TOKEN
RUN vercel env pull .env --environment=Development --token=$VERCEL_TOKEN

RUN npx prisma generate --schema ./prisma/schema.prisma

ENV POSTGRES_DATABASE=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_USER=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres?connect_timeout=300&schema=public
ENV POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres?connect_timeout=300&schema=public
ENV POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING=postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres?connect_timeout=300&schema=public
ENV POSTGRES_PORT=5432

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]

I have found nothing online for this error, nobody ever seemed to have this issue. I purged all docker containers and ran docker system prune with a clean rebuild but no luck. I don't know what else to try here.
Edit: my dockerignore:
**/node_modules
.next
.swc
.env


Are you seeing these errors when you're building the image or running the container?  It looks like the first error might be coming from your postinstall hook, so you might need to COPY the schema file into the image before you RUN npm install.  The volumes: block means you aren't actually running any of the code in your image, which can result in unpredictable behavior depending on what's on the host system; does deleting that entire block make any difference?

@DavidMaze I see these errors when I run docker-compose up --build. I also think that the first error comes from the postinstall script, although I thought that the schema was available and didn't need to be copied as I added the prisma folder to the volumes block. And what do you mean with the volumes block causing my code not to run anything in the image? I added these volumes to have them in sync with the container when I write code.

Ok so after fiddling around, I have somehow resolved the issue, but I am not quite sure why.
I removed the postinstall script in order to be able to spin up the container. Then I get the jose error as stated in my question but at least the container is running. I entered the container with docker exec -it hey-shop-web-1 bash and there I deleted the node_modules folder. I then ran npm install inside the container, stopped the containers and ran docker-compose up without the build flag. And now everything was working, however I could not run docker-compose up --build without getting this jose error again. This part I was able to solve by changing my Dockerfile from COPY package.json ./ to COPY package*.json ./. And now it works perfectly every time.
In the end the only thing I did was to change my Dockerfile to:
FROM node:20

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

RUN npm install --global vercel@latest

COPY . .

ARG VERCEL_TOKEN
RUN vercel env pull .env --environment=Development --token=$VERCEL_TOKEN

ENV POSTGRES_DATABASE=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_USER=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres?connect_timeout=300&schema=public
ENV POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres?connect_timeout=300&schema=public
ENV POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING=postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres?connect_timeout=300&schema=public
ENV POSTGRES_PORT=5432

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]

I thought that somehow my MacOS node_modules got into the Linux container and that caused the issue, but I don't know how that can be when I specifically added **/node_modules to the .dockerignore and I am installing them in my Dockerfile anyways. But I also noticed, that the installation of node modules was way quicker now. When I had the errors coming up, the npm install would take almost 500 seconds whereas after the fix it is now at roughly 30 seconds. I read somewhere that npm install would take so long in a docker container when it synced with the main OS. I think this might be what happened and that the install now is so quick is evidence that now there is no syncing going on. But I don't know how that would have happened in the first place.
Secondly, the postinstall error vanished as well. I was able to remove the prisma generate process from the Dockerfile and add the postinstall script back to the package.json. (Luckily, as I actually needed the postinstall for hosting on vercel)
If someone has any explanation or an idea of what is going on there, I appreciate your input.

If you are using your postinstall script to do prisma generate. You must make sure when building your image, the image has a copy of your prisma files
Example, I often use the Dockerfile template provided by NextJS here:
Thus I added the following COPY command to ensure the Dockerimage has my prisma files.
# Template from https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile


FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Prisma files must be copied. Comment this line if prisma is not installed
COPY prisma/ /app/prisma/

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi


# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1

RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run build; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm run build; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV=production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Set the correct permission for prerender cache
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT=3000

# server.js is created by next build from the standalone output
# https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/output
ENV HOSTNAME="0.0.0.0"
CMD ["node", "server.js"]


As you can see in my original question, I have added the prisma folder as a volume. Thus docker has access to it.


And this is the part where I get stuck. I don't understand why suddenly this error appears. I am on a recent version of jose, have checked their forums and find nothing.

https://github.com/panva/jose/issues/690#issuecomment-2194955332
Just run npm upgrade jose

Jose is already on the most recent version

Which is why you're not getting the error as per your own answer.
